# Adding sibling element in ElementTree with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

With XML such as

```
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>
```

I need to add a sibling of  something like

```
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
  <b'>
  </b'>
</a>
```

Does ElementTree has a function to add a sibling node?
If not, I guess I need a function to get a parent node and add a child node, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

In the standard lib's version, you cannot directly access the parent, you'll have to work down from the parent, or keep track of parent-child relations yourself, read [these tips](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#accessing-parents) (from the author of the library).

If you use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) however, there is the `getparent()` method (you have `getnext()` and `getprevious()` as well), but even more convenient: there is `addnext()` and `addprevious()`.

So, choose one of these solutions, based on what ElementTree implementation you are using (or maybe even switch your implementation)

Answer (score 1):

The default ElementTree implementation included in the Python Standard Library does not have a method to get a parent node.

However, if you can use [lxml's](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) etree implementation then there is a `getparent()` method.

Answer (score -4):

With what is at hand:

```
import re

def sibling(bal,text):
    print 'bal ==' + bal + '\n' # + '\n\n' + s

    def aux(match):
        # match.group(4) is '/' or None    
        return ("%s%s<%s'/>%s" % match.group(1,2,3,6) if match.group(4)
                else "%s%s<%s'>%s'>%s" % match.group(1,2,3,5,6))

    return re.sub('('
                  '(^\s*)<(' + bal + ')(?: [^/>]+)?'  # 2 and 3
                  '(?:(/)|>(?:.*?)((?:(?:\n|\r\n?)\\2)?</\\3))' # 4 and 5
                  '>(\n|\r\n?|\Z)' # 6
                  ')',
                  aux, text, flags = re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)


ch = """\
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>
"""

dh = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>
"""

print sibling('a',ch)
print '------------------------------------------------------'
print sibling('b',ch)
print '------------------------------------------------------'

for x in ('entry','dd:country_code','content','OTF','FECS',
          'BackEndCompatibility','BackEnd','Forth'):
    print sibling(x,dh)
    print '------------------------------------------------------'
```

Result:

```
bal ==a

<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>
<a'>
</a'>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==b

<a>
  <b>
  </b>
  <b'>
  </b'>
</a>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==entry

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>
<entry'>
</entry'>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==dd:country_code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <dd:country_code'></dd:country_code'>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==content

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <content'></content'>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==OTF

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
    <OTF'>
    </OTF'>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==FECS

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
      <FECS'>
      </FECS'>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==BackEndCompatibility

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
        <BackEndCompatibility'>
        </BackEndCompatibility'>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==BackEnd

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <BackEnd'/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
bal ==Forth

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <OTF>
      <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
        <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
            <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
            <Forth type="ziwi">d,;%er*dkj@jkber-uyr</Forth>
            <Forth'></Forth'>
        </BackEndCompatibility>
      </FECS>
    </OTF>
</entry>

------------------------------------------------------
```

It works for `'a'` and

```
"""\
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>
"""
```

but not

```
"""\
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>"""
```

Comment: -1 Read the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348, and `g/HTML/s//XML/`